# Applying differentiation with respect to a parameter, evaluate the following integral: $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha x} \frac{\sin(\beta x)}{x} dx$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

Applying differentiation with respect to a parameter, evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha x} \frac{\sin(\beta x)}{x} dx$$

I am struggling to solve this, furthermore, I do not understand their suggested approach.

if we create the function $F(\alpha, \beta) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha x} \frac{\sin(\beta x)}{x} dx$. If we find

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}F(\alpha, \beta) = f(\alpha), \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}F(\alpha, \beta) = f(\beta)$$

So then $F(\alpha, \beta) = \int f(\alpha) d\alpha + g_1(\beta)$ and $F(\alpha, \beta) = \int f(\beta) d\beta + g_1(\alpha)$ ?? I am not sure how we will be able to find the left over constant term here ....

**Edit:**

The last answer provided here: [Evaluating $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\frac{\sin{(bx)}}{x}dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3439419/evaluating-int-0-infty-e-ax-frac-sinbxxdx)

Provides a bit a starting point. We calculate the following:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax} \frac{ \sin(bx)}{x}dx = -\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial b} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax} \frac{ \sin(bx)}{x}dx = \frac{a}{a^2+b^2}$$

Now integrating with respect to the corresponding variables gives me $\frac{-1}{b}\arctan(\frac{a}{b}) +C_1$ and $\frac{1}{a}\arctan(\frac{b}{a})+C_2$. How do I go about finding the functions $C_1$ and $C_2$?

Comment: pls see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3439419/evaluating-int-0-infty-e-ax-frac-sinbxxdx

Comment: In the last answer provided (which sort of answers my question), I do not understand how $e^{-ax}e^{-bx}$ becomes $e^{-a+bi}x$ later on ... the answer needs to yield something with tangent.